# Is it possible to debug a python script that another executable is running?

Tags: python, debugging, visual-studio-debugging

I am modifying (my) python script that I am feeding to (not my) executable which runs it. I would like to be able to step through the script once the executable begins to step through it, but debug mode for the executable is not available to me.

Whereas Visual Studio allows you to attach to an external process to begin debugging, I wondered if I could put a pause in the program above where I want to step through and similarly attach to a python script. I wondered if there was a pdb integration that could allow this.

The executable does not seem to spin out a system call to python itself, nor can this script be called outside of the executable.

I use Visual Studio 2022, but am open to other options should they exist.

I added "import pdb" at the beginning of the file and tried to "Attach Process" from Visual Studio when the executable hit my **input("some text")** line in the python script. I attached to the executable and as expected... did not work.

Comment: "did not work" is not the most helpful description of the observed behavior. Please include a minimal case of your code and a more thorough description of the behavior you're observing.

Comment: It looks like you mess the concept of python pdb and vs pdb? You can take a look of my answer, if I misunderstand something,, please feel free to let me know. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I attached to the executable and as expected... did not work.

If you are talking about python program based on pdb file and using attach process feature to debug in visual studio, **I think the answer is NO.** In this situation, what you encountered is also expected.

You need to know the difference between the pdb of python and the pdb of visual studio, they are different.

## 1, concept of pdb in python.

The concept of pdb in python means a module that is Python's built-in debugger. The pdb module defines an interactive source code debugging environment. You can set breakpoints, step through code, view stack traces, list source code, and view and change the runtime state of source code. The name of the pdb module comes from an acronym for "Python DeBugger".

## 2, concept of pdb in visual studio.

But the concept of pdb in visual studio is different. The .pdb file of Visual Studio is a program database file (Program Database File), which contains the debugging information of the program. This information includes type information, function signatures, variable names, and other information that can help you debug a program in Visual Studio. The .pdb files in Visual Studio are not directly related to Python's pdb module.

Take a look of this Microsoft Official Document:

[Use debugger features](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/attach-to-running-processes-with-the-visual-studio-debugger?view=vs-2022#use-debugger-features)

You can see:

***To use the full features of the Visual Studio debugger (like hitting breakpoints) when attaching to a process, the app must exactly match your local source and symbols. That is, the debugger must be able to load the correct symbol (.pdb) files.***

So if you don't have a pdb file, unable to step debug program via attach process feature in visual studio is expected.

Check this official document:

[Specify symbol (.pdb) and source files in the Visual Studio debugger (C#, C++, Visual Basic, F#)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/specify-symbol-dot-pdb-and-source-files-in-the-visual-studio-debugger?view=vs-2022)

You will know that this is for C#, C++, Visual Basic, F#.

For python, the debug principle is in this place:

[Debug your Python code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/debugging-python-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2022)

You can see that the principle of the debug is totally different of the pdb file based attach program way.

Comment: In summary, I think what I wanted is not available. The program.exe must have python embedded in it as the task manager shows no instance that is running. I was not sure if there was some voodoo that VS had that could recognize the memory space reserved for the python script and the location where python was operating in the exe. Alas, I am resorting to the somewhat clunky python pdb via commandline. Thank you for your helpful response.